# Transform a GF2 multivariate polynomial so it has no cubic terms

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, transformation, substitution

I am using the quotient ring $\mathbb{GF}_2[x]/(x^2 + x)$ (the boolean ring) and I have a system of polynomials in $n$ variables with arbitrary degree. I'd like to find a bijective transformation whereby the resulting system contains no cubic terms, but does contain linear and quadratic terms, and may contain terms of degree $>3$. Ideally, I'd like to use a similar method to transform the resulting system *again* to remove the degree 4 terms (while not introducing any degree 3 terms, and continuing to have linear & quadratic terms).

Example:

$$
\begin{align}
f_1 &= x_1x_2x_3 + x_1x_2 + x_1x_4 + x_3 \\
f_2 &= x_1x_3x_4 + x_2x_4 + x_1 \\
\end{align}
$$

Transform this system using

$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= y_1 \\
x_2 &= y_2 \\
x_3 &= y_3y_4 + y_1 + y_3 \\
x_4 &= y_2y_3 + y_4 \\
\end{align}
$$

Giving you

$$
\begin{align}
f_1' &= y_1y_2y_3y_4 + y_1y_4 + y_3y_4 + y_1 + y_3 \\
f_2' &= y_1y_2y_3y_4 + y_2y_3 + y_1y_4 + y_2y_4 + y_1 \\
\end{align}
$$

Note that $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ contain no cubic terms. This example was created by guessing values until the desired result was achieved. Obviously I'd like some sort of algorithm to generate the transformation. The degree of the transformation is unimportant (I used degree 2 - which is a minimum here).

Comment: What kind of transformations are allowed? Linear won't do (and judging from the example is not intended to). Can we substitute $y_i=f_i$ making all linear? Probably not. Bijective?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Any transformation would work, although I imagine restricting it to a quadratic would make finding it easier/faster? Bijective is definitely a must

Comment: @flipchart Your example substitution is not bijective. You cannot get $x_1=0$, $x_2=0$, $x_3=1$, $x_4=1$ come out with any choice of $y_i$s. The first two equations force $y_1=y_2=0$. The last equation then forces $y_4=1$. But this fatally removes $y_3$ from the third.

Comment: Anyway, if you have only three variables, then you can never get rid of the term $x_1x_2x_3$ with a bijective substitution. The reason is that a boolean function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ takes the value $1$ for an odd number of inputs if and only if the term $x_1x_3x_3$ is present. If the substitution is bijective, it will not change this parity. Hence $y_1y_2y_3$ will remain.